# Корпус русских стоп слов

Tags: nlp

Где можно найти корпус русских стоп слов, который будет содержать: союзы, местоимения, частицы, предлоги и т.д. во всех формах, падежах, единственных и множественных числах?

Comment: Вопрос относится к nlp, т.к. удаление из текста стоп-слов это одна из задач nlp, у меня это удаление делается просто, ищу слово в корпусе, если оно там есть удалаяю его. Но т.к. стоп слова имеюи разные формы (он, его, ему, им и т.д.) нужен большой корпус со всеми такими формами. Поэтому и отнес вопрос к nlp, мало ли есть люди, которые nlp занимаются, и у которых имеется такой корпус.

Comment: Очень важный и правильный вопрос для задач машинного обучения. Приводить код в таком вопросе смысла мало...

Comment: [Тематичен ли поиск баз данных?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9804/213987)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://github.com/stopwords-iso/stopwords-ru

Я в свое время пользовался этим, вполне хватило